# Discord.NET audit log based invite tracker not sending desired message

Tags: c#, discord.net

I apologize to those of you that saw my last post reguarding. I see that it was too vague I was just not in the right headspace but hopefully this post sustains enough information about the issue. I have been trying to debug this auditlog based invite tracker for an absurd amount of time and have lost sanity. The idea behind this is that using a `onmemberjoin` event the bot can use the audit logs to fetch the invite that the user used to join the guild and will send a log with information about that to a specified log channel. I can see in the debugging that the auditlog is being collected but the message is not being sent. it seems from the information I gained trying to debug that it is somehow getting stopped between the `foreach` and the `if` statement the line under it somehow of which I have no clue on how that could be possible. If anyone could help me find the issue I would be extremely grateful.

```cs
private async Task OnMemberJoin(SocketGuildUser arg)
        {
            var g = arg.Guild;
            var channelId = await _servers.GetLogsAsync(g.Id);
            var chnlIdInt = Convert.ToInt64(channelId);
            if (chnlIdInt == 0) return;
            if (!g.CurrentUser.GuildPermissions.ViewAuditLog)
            {
                await _serverHelper.SendLogAsync(g, "Bot Does Not Have Sufficient Permissions",
                    "A event logger has failed its task because I do\nnot have `View Audit Log` permissions. To solve this error please\ngive me that permission");
                return;
            }

            var auditlogs = await g.GetAuditLogsAsync(1, null, null, null, ActionType.InviteUpdated)
                .FlattenAsync();


            foreach (var audit in auditlogs)
                if (audit.User is IUser && audit.Data is InviteUpdateAuditLogData d1)

                {
                    var inv3 = _client.Guilds
                        .OfType<InviteUpdateAuditLogData>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.After.Code.ToString().IndexOf(
                                                 d1.After.Code,
                                                 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) !=
                                             -1);
                    if (inv3 == null) return;

                    if (inv3 is IInvite iInvite)

                    {
                        var uses = d1.Before.MaxUses.Value - d1.After.MaxUses.Value;
                        await _serverHelper.SendLogAsync(g, "Invite Used",
                            $"An invite has been used.\nInvite: {iInvite.Url}\nTotal invite uses: `{uses.ToString()}`\nInvite created by: {iInvite.Inviter.Mention}");
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Assuming stopping between the `foreach` and the `if` means that it's not actually reaching the `if`, does the `auditlogs` variable even contain any data?

Comment: auditlogs should have data yes

Comment: **Should** have and *does** have are two different things. You should be confirming that it does and not assuming. Debug your code to see exactly where it is failing to do  what it should be doing then you can try to ascertain why.